# What are the original Greek expressions for "is predicated of", "applies to" and "belongs to"?

Tags: aristotle, translation

I'm re-reading Aristotle's Prior Analytics in which he expounds his syllogistic. In the text, instead of writing "All A is B", he usually writes "B is predicated of all A" or "B applies to all A" or "B belongs to all A". Having studied two semesters of ancient Greek many years ago, I'm afraid I have forgotten almost everything. Does anyone know the original Greek expressions for "is predicated of", "applies to" and "belongs to"? Any further grammatical explanations would be appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Since there is not yet a Greek Language stackexchange, I suggest migrating this question to the philosophy stackexchange.

Comment: There you go http://www.hs-augsburg.de/~harsch/graeca/Chronologia/S_ante04/Aristoteles/ari_a100.html

Comment: Could you give an example with reference, that we may look it up?

Comment: The bilingual edition is here http://www.loebclassics.com/view/aristotle-prior_analytics/1938/pb_LCL325.199.xml?result=148&rskey=BWOGwM

Comment: Thanks Alex, Loeb Classics is exactly the one I'm using, though mine is a book version.

Comment: Thanks Keelan, for example with reference, please see my reply to Mauro below.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Aristotle's terminology in general, see [Aristotle's Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/#GloAriTer).

Regarding your question :

> in *An.Pr.* the sentences are always composed of two nouns and the copula “belongs to” (*huparchein*).

See [An.Pr.Book A, 24a15-21](http://www.hs-augsburg.de/~harsch/graeca/Chronologia/S_ante04/Aristoteles/ari_a111.html) :

> I call belonging 'to every' or 'to none' *universal*; I call belonging 'to some,' 'not to some,' or 'not to every,' *particular*, [...].

Also "applies" (see 26a33-35) is *ὑπάρχει*.

---

Regarding "predication" : *katêgorein* (verb); *katêegoroumenon* (“what is predicated”).

Comment: Thanks Mauro, do you know also the original Greek expressions for "is predicated of" (e.g., An.Pr. Book A, 25b37-40) and "applies to" (e.g., An.Pr. Book A, 26a33-35)?

Comment: You've been of great help, thanks again, two thumbs up!